# Wicegrid pagination and filters not working after AJAX update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a wicegrid that I update via AJAX(based on the value selected by a drop down). Problem is that after the update, the filters and pagination stops working on left-mouse click(works on right click!). Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

I have used wicegrid on a number of pages in the same project(without AJAX update), and this issue does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming you use jquery):
    $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
     put code you want to run;
    });
probably your script is not working because it's in document.ready scope.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found a straightforward workaround for this issue - call the initWiceGrid() function after you refresh the grid.

Comment: Hi, Even I'm facing the same issue. May i know where to call the above method

Comment: As wice_grid doesn't have any inherent AJAX capabilities, it'll depend a bit on how you've implemented it. In our particular case, we made the "Search" button use `link_to remote: true`, and then used a .js.erb template to render the grid's contents only.

Finally we catch the `ajax:complete` event on the submit button and use that function to call initWiceGrid and anything else we need to re-run.